# c# EPPlus: how to fix - ShowFilter doesn't work

Tags: epplus, epplus-4

The issue with Table.ShowFilter, using EPPLUS library.
Created new ExcelTable in the sheet, but can't apply Table.ShowFilter = false.
The filters are still in the table.
TableStyle and StyleName work fine.

```
ExcelTable et = (ExcelTable)Table;
int firstRow = newRow;
int lastRow;
if (DataStructure.Data != null)
      lastRow = newRow + DataStructure.Data.Count();
else
      lastRow = newRow + 1;

int firstColumn = OriginalAddress.StartColumn;
int lastColumn = OriginalAddress.EndColumn;

ExcelRange rg = ws.Cells[firstRow, firstColumn, lastRow, lastColumn];

Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
string str_guid = guid.ToString();
string tableName = et.Name + "_" + str_guid;

ExcelTable tab = wsTarget.Tables.Add(rg, tableName);
//  tab.ShowHeader = et.ShowHeader;
//  tab.TableStyle = et.TableStyle;
//  tab.StyleName = et.StyleName;
tab.ShowFilter = false;
```

[Right table is desired result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPmcw.png)

Please, help to fix!

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want to mean?

```
tab.ShowHeader = false;
```

This very little example works here :

```
        using (ExcelPackage xls = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws2 = xls.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("f1");
            OfficeOpenXml.Table.ExcelTable tab = ws2.Tables.Add(new ExcelAddressBase("a1:e5"), "table");
            //tab.TableStyle = et.TableStyle;
            //tab.StyleName = et.StyleName;
            tab.ShowFilter = false;

            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(@"d:\temp\test.xlsx");
            xls.SaveAs(f);
        }
```

Comment: Hi! No, ShowHeader works well, but ShowFilter not. In case tab.ShowFilter = false; filter buttons are still in the table.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you don't want.  Can you post a screen shot of expected result?

Comment: Daniel, please, take a look to the link above. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Which version of epplus are you using?  I'm using 4.5.2.1 and it works like you are expecting for.  If you can't, give us more details, on `tab.TableStyle = et.TableStyle;   tab.StyleName = et.StyleName;` and maybe elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Daniel, is also 4.5.2.1. Code example updated, commented tab.TableStyle = et.TableStyle; tab.StyleName = et.StyleName; Checked one more time - still active filters.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Excel for Mac ver.16.18(181014)

Comment: Just to be sure, can you test your Excel file in another computer (with another Excel version, or a Windows version of Excel)?  Or, is there any way you can upload your file in StackOverflow?

Comment: Daniel, thank you a lot! Will try tomorrow on Windows computer. I'm working on template engine, so, there are two files: template and target.xlsx. I generate the target from new, clear workbook, based on template and json datasource. Which one do you mean to upload? Generated target?

Comment: The generated one.  And, did you try if my little test work on your side?  You should try on a little(empty) file to see if issue is still there or not.

Comment: Daniel, your code works well on my computer. Looks like the problem is after ws2.DeleteColumn(1, 1), which i'm using...

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the bug.
Adding ws2.DeleteColumn(1, 1) to the code, add filters to the table, even with tab.ShowFilter = false.

Workaround: put tab.ShowFilter = false right before file saving.

```
 using (ExcelPackage xls = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws2 = xls.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("f1");
            OfficeOpenXml.Table.ExcelTable tab = ws2.Tables.Add(new ExcelAddressBase("d3:g8"), "table");
            //tab.TableStyle = et.TableStyle;
            //tab.StyleName = et.StyleName;

            ws2.DeleteColumn(1, 1);

            tab.ShowFilter = false;

            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(@"test.xlsx");
            xls.SaveAs(f);
        }
```